# Regular expression searching a string?

Tags: java, regex

I need to be able to create a regular expression that will search through any string in Java and match this particular expression.

Reg Match:
      ./ ADD NAME=    <--- I need to match this regular expression in any string that I read into the file and it normally would be in position 1 through 13

I am looking for this in the first 10 characters of any string because I have to return the name that follows the equals sign to make a file name with so the whole line would looking like the following.

Question: Why does my expression not match in any of the strings?

File Line:

```
   ./ ADD NAME=FILE02 
        ...more records would go here...
   ./ ADD NAME=FILE332 
        ...more records would go here...
   ./ ADD NAME=FILE3 
        ...more records would go here...
   ./ ADD NAME=FILE-1A
        ...more records would go here...
```

Code:

```
    private void locatedFileName(String s) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("./ ADD name=");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    boolean b = m.matches();

    if (b) {
        System.out.println("True");
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");
    }
}

**private void locatedFileName(String s) {
        if (s.matches("./ ADD name=")) {
            System.out.println("True");
        } else {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
}**
```

All the Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class test {

    test(){
    }

    private void locatedFileName(String s) {
        if (s.matches("./ ADD name=")) {
            System.out.println("True");
        } else {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
    }

    private void testReadTextFile() {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\itpr13266\\Desktop\\TestFile.txt"));
            String line = null;
            //Will read through the file until EOF
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                locatedFileName(line); //test to see if the "./ Add name=" is found in any of the strings
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Try-Catch Message - " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        test t = new test();
        t.testReadTextFile();
    }
}
```

Newest Code that I tried:

code:

```
        final String REGEX = ("(?i)\\./\\s+ADD\\s+NAME\\s*=");
    final String REGEXtemp = ("\\s+ADD\\s");

    //Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEXtemp);
                Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    boolean b = m.matches();

    if (b) {
        System.out.println("True");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Reg not found in string!");
    }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: don't forget `.` and `/` are special characters and needs to be escaped

Comment: A regex seems overkill here. Why not just test that the beginning of the string matches your search string and then return the rest of the string?

Comment: @user1631616 +1 for your comment. I think `.` is the culprit here. You should answer the question as soon as OP reformulates.

Comment: That would work just testing the first part of the string. I am working on this at work so I might as well learn as much as I possible can.

Comment: I would escape the dot (and the spaces, but not necessary). `"\\./\\ ADD\\ name="`

Comment: How would I rectify this problem of the . in this case. I have tried to escape it with the / so I have this /.// ADD NAME= and this still did not work.

Comment: @DougHauf read the comments better. You don't escape special characters in patterns by using a forward slash, you escape them by using a double backslash.

Comment: `"\\."` string. What ends up going to the regex engine: `\.`

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\.\\/ ADD name=]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        boolean b = m.matches(); ---- for some reason this is still not working. I must not have everything set up in the Pattern.compile correctly.

Comment: You don't need to escape the `/`, it is not a metachar. Your problem is with the `case insensitive` modifier (see my post). Or change it to ADD,NAME in your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***info*** -
Try it like this to get  the substring:

```
 Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\./\\s+ADD\\s+name\\s*=");
 Matcher m = patt.matcher( s );
 while (m.find()) 
 // or if (m.find())
 { 

 }
```

Matches I think has to match the whole string (gotcha)
to match the whole thing. For that use this regex:

```
 Pattern.compile("(?si).*?\\./\\s+ADD\\s+name\\s*=.*");
```

---

Your regex should have matched, even with the dot metachar you've used.
It's possible there are tabs instead of spaces there.

I guess you could replace space literal with whitespace class.
Something like this:
**edit**  - Oh, you need case insensitive too
because ADD,name doesn't match ADD,NAME

```
 #  Pattern.compile("(?i)\\./\\s+ADD\\s+name\\s*=");

 (?i) \./ \s+ ADD \s+ name \s* =
```

Expanded regex with comments

```
 #  Pattern.compile("(?i)\\./\\s+ADD\\s+name\\s*=");

 (?i)      # Case insensitive modifier
           #     for all subsequent alpha literals
 \.        # literal dot
 /         # literal forward slash
 \s+       # 1 or more whitespace characters
 ADD       # 'ADD'
 \s+       # 1 or more whitespace characters 
 name      # 'name'
 \s*       # 0 or more whitespace characters
 =         # '='
```

Comment: Tried this and it still will not match. Just to make certain that i understand the expression here. the + is just used to append each part together. The (?i) is that for the tabs in the beginning.

Comment: @Doug Hauf - Added, regex explanation. I don't know why it wouldn't work, it should though. What is the exact quoted string you are using? Are you using it in all the places the old regex  was in?

Comment: I don't know Java well but, It might be you are using the wrong match function. See if there is a 'Matches' one. Some langs use auto-full line matches where it has to match the whole line. Some just match the substring.

Comment: Ok, you have to use `Matcher.find()` instead of `matches`. This just finds substrings.